# Z3 solve-eq how to use

Tags: z3

I'm trying to understand how to use solve-eq, I expected Z3 to solve this

```
(declare-const mem (Array Int Int))
(declare-const adr_a Int)
(declare-const a Int)
(assert (= (select mem adr_a) a))
(assert (<= 0 (select mem adr_a)))
(apply solve-eqs)
```

into

```
(<= 0 a)
```

but I get instead

```
(<= 0 (select mem adr_a))
```

can I specify what varibales should be simplified? any other tactique could do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(assert (= b a))
(assert (<= 0 b))
(apply solve-eqs)
```

the output is:

```
(goals (goal (<= 0 a) :precision precise :depth 1) )
```